# EOF while parsing in python

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, syntax-error, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a game that prints shuffled letters and the user has to create a word/s from that list. Users have options to exit, view scores, and continue playing. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. The error said "Syntax error: unexpected EOF while parsing"

So far I've come up with this code.
Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

def printPreorder(root):
     if root:
        print(root.val),
        printPreorder(root.left)
        printPreorder(root.right)


class stack:
     def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item): 
        return self.items.append(item)
    
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

print ("Create 3 words using the letters")
root = Node('a')
root.right = Node('n')
root.left = Node ('t')
printPreorder(root)
print("-----------------------------------")

s1 = stack()
while (s1.size() <3):
    try:
        FirstList = (input("Enter the word you created: "))
        if (FirstList == 'an'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

        elif (FirstList == 'ant'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

        elif (FirstList == 'tan'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

    finally:
        print(s1.items)

 legend1 = (input("Choose next move 1 = Countinue to the next round 2 = Show score3 = Exit Legend: "))
    if legend1 == '3':
        exit1 = (input("Are you sure you want to exit? 1 = yes 2 = no"))
        if (exit1 == '1'): 
            break
        elif (exit1 == '2'):
            return
        else:
            print("Enter valid legend: ")

    elif legend1 == '2':
        print(s1.size())

    elif legend1 == '1':
        s2 = stack()
        print ("Create 3 words using the letters")
        root = Node('i')
        root.right = Node('d')
        root.left = Node ('m')
        printPreorder(root)
        print("-----------------------------------")
        s1 = stack()
        while (s2.size() <3):
            try:
                SecondList = (input("Enter the word you created: "))
                if (SecondList == 'hid'):
                    s2.push(SecondList)

                elif (SecondList == 'dim'):
                    s2.push(SecondList)

                elif (SecondList == 'id'):
                    s2.push(SecondList)

            finally:
                print(s2.items)
```

Please help me fix the syntax error.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Your error is unreproducible due to other errors such as indentation, and using `return` outside of a function. Could you either fix these errors, or provide a simpler toy example?

Answer (score 0):

This should run now.
You cannot use `return` or `break` outside of functions and loops. I think what you want is `exit()`

You can avoid EoF problems by using text editors made for coding such as **VS Code**. They will show you where these errors are located.

Lastly, you can use `\n` in strings to add newlines. This will make your `print` output more readable.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

def printPreorder(root):
    if root:
        print(root.val),
        printPreorder(root.left)
        printPreorder(root.right)


class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item): 
        return self.items.append(item)
    
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

print ("Create 3 words using the letters")
root = Node('a')
root.right = Node('n')
root.left = Node ('t')
printPreorder(root)
print("-----------------------------------")

s1 = stack()
while (s1.size() <3):
    try:
        FirstList = (input("Enter the word you created: "))
        if (FirstList == 'an'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

        elif (FirstList == 'ant'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

        elif (FirstList == 'tan'):
            s1.push(FirstList)

    finally:
        print(s1.items)

legend1 = (input("Choose next move\n1 = Countinue to the next round\n2 = Show score\n3 = Exit\nLegend: "))
if legend1 == '3':
    exit1 = (input("Are you sure you want to exit?\n1 = yes\n2 = no"))
    if (exit1 == '1'): 
        exit()
    elif (exit1 == '2'):
        exit()
    else:
        print("Enter valid legend: ")

elif legend1 == '2':
    print(s1.size())

elif legend1 == '1':
    s2 = stack()
    print ("Create 3 words using the letters")
    root = Node('i')
    root.right = Node('d')
    root.left = Node ('m')
    printPreorder(root)
    print("-----------------------------------")
    s1 = stack()
    while (s2.size() <3):
        try:
            SecondList = (input("Enter the word you created: "))
            if (SecondList == 'hid'):
                s2.push(SecondList)

            elif (SecondList == 'dim'):
                s2.push(SecondList)
            
            elif (SecondList == 'id'):
                s2.push(SecondList)
            
        finally:
            print(s2.items)
```